# Remove rows with empty values when evaluating eclat and apriori itemsets

Tags: r, machine-learning, apriori

I am working in R and have a dataset which looks like the following

```
[1, 2, 3, ""]
[1, 2, "", 4]
[1,"", "", ""]
```

I am reading these values into a transaction object and then passing them to eclat or apriori for frequent itemset evaluation.  The problem arises when my frequent itemsets look like the following:

```
{1,""}
{2,3,""}
```

I would like to remove these rows from the calculation as I think it's slowing down the processing and also doesn't make any sense from a prediction standpoint.  Can you please help?  My R code is below.

```
tr <- read.transactions("Items.csv", rm.duplicates=TRUE, format="basket",sep=",")

dataset1 <- as.vector(t(dataset1))

frequentItems <- eclat (tr, parameter = list(supp = 0.03, minlen=2, maxlen = 4)) 

inspect(frequentItems)
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: The structure of your dataset looks very confusing for R-folks. Can you provide us with some code we can actually try ourselves, and maybe add the package from which your function comes (that's the `arules` package, right?)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have, boils down to `arules` thinking that "" is an item. So if you don't want that, you'll have to remove all these values from your data first. The likely culprit is the original csv file. It contains empty fields, and they're translated to an `""` item.

So the best way to get rid of this, is make sure that your csv file actually has a correct format. It should look like this:

```
item1, item2
item1
item2, item3
```

And not this

```
"item1", "item2"
"item1", ""
"item2", "item3"
```

To solve the problem in code, convert to a list first:

```
thelist <- as(tr, "list")

thelist <- lapply(thelist, function(i){
  i[i != ""]
})

trnew <- as(thelist, "transactions")
```

En example showing you how it works:

```
library(arules)
# Example data
a_list <- list(
  c("item1","item2"),
  c("item1",""),
  c("item2","item3"),
  c("","item3")
  )

tr <- as(a_list, "transactions")

frequentItems <- eclat (tr, parameter = list(supp = 0.03, minlen=2, maxlen = 4)) 
inspect(frequentItems)

#>    items         support
#>[1] {item2,item3} 0.25   
#>[2] {,item3}      0.25   
#>[3] {,item1}      0.25   
#>[4] {item1,item2} 0.25   

# Conversion
thelist <- as(tr, "list")
thelist <- lapply(thelist, function(i){
  i[i != ""]
})
trnew <- as(thelist, "transactions")

frequentItems <- eclat (trnew, parameter = list(supp = 0.03, minlen=2, maxlen = 4))
inspect(frequentItems)

#>    items         support
#>[1] {item2,item3} 0.25   
#>[2] {item1,item2} 0.25
```